# Как удалить объект из объекта массивов по полю price?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Есть объект такого вида:

```
const newArr = {
      month: [
        { count: 1, price: 10, _id: '63239a84e7c9298231788ce6' },
        { count: 2, price: 20, _id: '63239a84e7c929345tqgr46' },
      ],
      year: [{}],
      weak: [{}],
      day: [{}],
    }
```

Мне нужно по полю price удалить объект из массива, я делаю что-то типа этого:

```
Object.entries(currentPrices).map(([key, value]) => ({
   [key]: value.filter((dateItem) => dateItem.price !== price),
}))
```

Получаю, мягко говоря, не то, что нужно

Comment: Тебе нужно оставить только те объекты массива month где есть цена ил где её нету?

Comment: а что такое currentPrices?

Comment: и price тоже пишет, что не определено...

Answer (score 0):

```
const newArr = {
      month: [
        { count: 1, price: 10, _id: '63239a84e7c9298231788ce6' },
        { count: 2, price: 20, _id: '63239a84e7c929345tqgr46' },
        { count: 2, price: 0, _id: '63239a84e7c929345tqgr46' },
        { count: 2, price: 30, _id: '63239a84e7c929345tqgr46' },
      ],
      year: [{}],
      weak: [{}],
      day: [{}],
    }

// Если нужно оставить только те объекты в которые есть price
newArr.month = newArr.month.filter((item) => item.price)

// Если нужно оставить только те объекты у которых нет цены
newArr.month = newArr.month.filter((item) => !item.price)
```